# Handling missing data for sea level in regression

Tags: regression, missing-data

I am doing a simple regression where one of the regressors is the sea level and another regressor is US region. For the central region in the US, I have obviously no data for sea level. I am wondering how I should treat the missing data without introducing bias ?

Replacing NA by a sea level of 0 or a country average would definitely bias the results. I am also not sure that multiple imputation techniques are appropriate in this context.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: In this case, the US is divided in 6 regions: 5 regions have a coastal area with a contact with the sea and one region called "MID" has no contact with the sea, so there is no sea level for that region by "construction".

Comment: How are you measuring sea level?  Also, what's the context? What's the dependent variable?  How are you going to handle the fact that, while most regions have coastlines, the size of the coastlines are not the same?

Comment: It's in an actuarial context where the dependent variable is mortality rate and I am trying to determine the relation between mortality and climate variables. I am using the sea level "Actuaries Climate Index", see here: https://actuariesclimateindex.org/data/component-definitions/ "Sea level measurements are on a monthly basis via tide gauges located at 76 stations with reliable time series."

Comment: I would consider multiple imputation for handling most missing data scenarios, but I think the deeper issue here is that the premise isn't very sensical. To give a crude analogy, it's like you're trying to predict mortality from penile lenght and are asking what value to use for persons with no male genitals. Is there no other way to express a plausible *mechanism* behind the predictor, such as perhaps testosterone levels in my example (which is better quantifiable and more importantly meaningful in all humans)?

Comment: Thanks @PBulls, I totally agree. I like the idea of considering multiple imputation. Another possibility is to consider two models : one with sea level for coastal regions and one without sea level for the central region. Maybe it will make even more sense than multiple imputation.